# Growing crystals that are in a magnetic field or subjected to an electric field

Tags: crystal-structure, magnetism, recrystallization, liquid-crystals, crystal-field-theory

I know different crystals resonant at different frequencies but **is it possible to grow crystal at a certain frequency**.  An example would be growing crystals using Epsom salt or Alum in a magnetic field or when it's subjected to an electric field while two electrodes are submerged into the saturated solution.

The reason I ask is I know they can "program" magnetic fields one company doing this is called [Correlated Magnetics](http://www.polymagnet.com/)

A video that explains ["programming" magnets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=drD416THU7Y)

I would like to do something similar but with crystals.  I do know there are ways to test the resonance of crystal oscillators [Video showing how to find resonance frequency of crystal oscillator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vv2Xcjga_Vc&list=PL80oNe5cvR7_XfZ6w0gYMd-xHwvC2xzX8)

[How to test Rochelle salt piezoelectric crystals voltage oscilloscope](https://youtu.be/R9m79oWdOZI)

Now I'm just trying to see and find out if I can "program" crystals at various frequencies by subjecting them to magnetic fields or electric fields.  Has anyone tried this or know of research being done?

Comment: I'm afraid your idea is bad. One can influence magnetic properties using magnetic field, but they are too weak to influence mechanical properties. Even if you'd get one strong enough it would be highly dangerous.

Comment: On second thought maybe you could make sth with piezoelectric or magnetostrictive materials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main influence on resonant frequency of a crystal is mechanical: the mass of the crystal and the restoring force of elasticity cause the crystal to vibrate at a specific frequency when disturbed. [To fine-tune the crystal, bits may be chemically or abrasively removed](http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/data/crystals/quartz-crystals-resonator.php) or the [mass may be increased slightly by rubbing with graphite](http://www.qsl.net/n6ev/ft243.txt).

That said, crystal orientation *does* influence resonant frequency because the [modulus of elasticity of a crystal such as quartz is anisotropic](http://www.crystran.co.uk/optical-materials/quartz-crystal-sio2), i.e. it varies significantly in which plane it is measured. Perhaps applying a strong magnetic or electrostatic field would change the resonant frequency -- but you would need to isolate the effect on the crystal from that of its mounting, particularly if there are metallic contacts.